# Why does JsonResult produce 500 internal server error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to retrieve a value from my Microsoft SQL Server database. It is a nullable "bit".

The code to retrieve

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult WishesVisit()
{
    int firmaid = SessionExtensions.GetFirmaId(Session);
    var firma = db.Firma.Where(x => x.firma_id == firmaid).FirstOrDefault();

    if (firma != null)
    {
        if (firma.oensker_besog != null)
        {
            if ((bool)firma.oensker_besog)
            {
                return Json("true");
            }
            else
            {
                return Json("false");
            }
        }
    }

    return Json("null"); 
}
```

And the code to retrieve:

```
$.getJSON('WishesVisit', function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Why am i getting a 500 internal server error?

The debugger doesn't catch any exception.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is most likely because ASP.NET MVC does not allow JSON requests using GET by default. You can add `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` as a second parameter to your Json call:

```
return Json("true", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

If not, can you provide a error message?

Comment: thanks. Any idea why ASP.NET MVC does not allow JSON requests.

Comment: @eranotzap MVC is protecting you from the exploit known as [JSON Hijacking](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/) wherein you could potentially expose sensitive data if the GET request returns a JSON array.