# Why is this throwing an internal server error

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I have this in my controller;

```
    public JsonResult Json_GetStoreList()
    {
        StoresData stores = new StoresData();
        return Json(stores.All());
    }
```

Then in my partial view I have this;

```
$(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Maintenance/Json_GetStoreList',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

The controller is returning an IEnumerable list of an object called Store which looks like this;

```
public class Store
{
    public Guid id { get; set; }
    public int number { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

The Javascript is throwing error

> 500 - Internal Server Error

Comment: Put a break point on the server method and see what's throwing. Use Fiddler2 and watch the request traffic and use web view on the 500 error response, you'll see the .Net exception page.

Comment: Try adding this contentType: 'application/json

Comment: probably an exception, debug and catch it so we can now what it is.

Comment: You should be logging your errors somewhere my friend.

Comment: Never mind, found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081372/why-does-jsonresult-produce-500-internal-server-error

Answer (score 0):

try to add the WebMethod attribute

```
[WebMethod]     
public JsonResult Json_GetStoreList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

in **Controller**

```
[HttpPost]  
  public ActionResult Json_GetStoreList(MyViewModel myViewModel)  
  {            
    StoresData stores = new StoresData();
     return Json(stores , JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
  }
```

in **Javascript**

```
 $.ajax({
         url: '/Maintenance/Json_GetStoreList',
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'json',
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         async: true,
         processData: false,
         error: function (xhr) {
            alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
         },
         success: function (result) {
            CheckIfInvoiceFound(result);
         },

      });
```

Comment: Change the type to GET and the controller to HttpGet and the request behaviour to AllowGet and you have the answer